# Swift playground in Xcode 6.2: println doesn't print anything inside willSet/didSet

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I've just started learning Swift after a long way with Objective-C. As recommended by Apple, I've chosen playgrounds to code and learn. Here's the code:

```html
class Polygon
{
    var color:UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    
    var numberOfSides:Int = 0 {
        willSet(newNumber)
        {
            println("willSet is being called")
        }
        didSet(newNumber)
        {
            println("didSet is being called")
            
            //just to make sure didSet is called
            numberOfSides = 12345678
        }
    }
}

var polygon1 = Polygon()

polygon1.numberOfSides = 222222
polygon1.numberOfSides = 1

var polygon2 = Polygon()
polygon2.numberOfSides = 12313
```

It's as simple as 2+2, and the polygons behave as expected. The question is: **where is the result of println()** calls (see the image embedded)? Thanks in advance.
[image: Code execution in a playground]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output of print/println functions goes to console - you can see it in assistant editor (use app menu View -> Assistant editor -> Show assistant editor to show it, or keyboard `alt+cmd+enter` shortcut)

Comment: Thank you very much! What would I do without your answer... Apparently the console you mentioned is not the same as so called "Debug console" which I was relying on. Your answer is precise and helpful!